# How to override Gradle `rootProject.name` from the command line?

Tags: gradle

I'm writing a test that does a build and publish to Artifactory. Since I don't want the test to fail if it's run concurrently (eg by separate build jobs or developers), I'd like to override `rootProject.name`. Can this be done from the command line? I've tried `-ProotProject.name=${module}` and `-Pproject.archivesBaseName=${module}` but they're not working (the latter does have some effect, but the artifact is still published with the `rootProject.name` setting in `settings.gradle`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to script `settings.gradle`. For example:

```
rootProject.name = System.getProperty("rootProjectName")
```

Now you can run with `gradle build -DrootProjectName=foo`.

Comment: In case you need default behaviour when variable `rootProjectName` is missing: `rootProject.name = System.getProperty("rootProjectName") ?: new File('.').canonicalFile.name`

Answer (score 3):

The following is a slightly simpler version when you need the default behavior that just passes through the default when it's not being overwritten.

```
rootProject.name = System.getProperty('rootProjectName') ?: rootProject.name
```